# jQuery code to fill out fields by hitting "Same as Shipping" not copying over my State field. Any ideas why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad

jQuery code to fill out fields by hitting "Same as Shipping" not working on iPad in Safari. Any ideas?

This only happens on iPad devices from what I've seen, and ones that use Safari. Tested on 1st generation iPads. Seems to only effect the State field. Very weird.

The shipping field is called "State_Ship", and the billing field is simply "State". Both are select drop down fields with all of the states as options.

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#BillingAsShipping').click(function(){
    if($('#BillingAsShipping').is(':checked')){
    $('#FirstName').val($('#FName_Ship').val());
    $('#LastName').val($('#LName_Ship').val());
    $('#Phone').val($('#Phone_Ship').val());
    var state = $('#State_Ship option:selected').val();
    $('#State option[value=' + state + ']').attr('selected','selected');
    $('#Company').val($('#Company_Ship').val());
    $('#Address1').val($('#Address1_Ship').val());
    $('#Address2').val($('#Address2_Ship').val());
    $('#City').val($('#City_Ship').val());
    $('#PostalCode').val($('#PostalCode_Ship').val());
    var country = $('#Country_Ship option:selected').val();
    $('#Country option[value=' + country + ']').attr('selected','selected');
    populateShippingMethods('Default');
    } else { 
    //Clear on uncheck
    $('#FirstName').val("");
    $('#LastName').val("");
    $('#Phone').val("");
    $('#State option[value=Nothing]').attr('selected','selected');
    $('#Company').val("");
    $('#Address1').val("");
    $('#Address2').val("");
    $('#City').val("");
    $('#PostalCode').val("");
    $('#Country').val("");
    populateShippingMethods('Default');
    };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite possible that you need to use the "change" event instead of the click event.

`$("#BillingAsShipping").on("change", function(){ //... });`

Comment: If that was the case, would it effect all of the other fields too instead of just the State field? Just curious is all.